# Deploying rails app on Digital Ocean with passenger and NGINX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, deployment, passenger, digital-ocean

This is the very first app I am deploying so I'm not 100% familiar with the whole process.

Right now, all my code for the app is on my server, and if i run rails s and bind it to my droplet ip, it shows up perfectly(i.e. if i go to myipaddress:3000).

But, if I just go to myipaddress on my browser, i just get a 500 error page. 
I am confused about the whole process, do i have to have my rails s running the whole time when deployed and running on the server?

If not what am I doing wrong and how can i fix it so that it just shows up when I go to my droplet ipaddress?

My nginx.conf file has its server name pointed to my droplet ip and its root pointed at my apps root folder. 
Also, im not getting any errors logged into my nginx/log/error.log file

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to start server with `rails s`.

You just need to install passenger and nginx for start application with installation of ruby on rails.

And if you just want to check your app is running or not then start server with `rails s` into digitalocean and try to open it with browser with `ip:3000' then it will work.

From this [Ref. link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) you can start with passenger and nginx.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply. I tried following the guide you provided and now im getting the **This webpage is not available** page on chrome, saying the connection attempt was rejected. I set up the /etc/nginx/sites-available/appname properly to point to my ip droplet ip address and my app's public folder, and i also verified that my nginx was running.  As before, if i run rails s and bind it to my droplet ip, and go to ip:3000, the app is running fine.  The error message that i get on chrome is _ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED_.

Comment: Can you paste your file which is in sites-available and also nginx.conf So I will let you know what is problem.